# Converting table directly to tree structure with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hdf5

I want to convert this csv file Format:

[image: csv]

into a hdf5 file with this structure:

[image]

I am using Pandas. Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: Have you seen this [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html)

Comment: I am reading it but I seem to not be able to find what I am looking for.

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov, it seems like all you want is a nested dictionary. Why would you want HDF5 to store this? HDF5 is usually good for big data or for transportability.

Comment: @jpp you think it is the wrong Approach? My Task is to calculate all datasets in another hdf5 which belong to a, b or c. This info however is given in the csv above. So I thought I should convert the csv to a hdf5 and merge both hdf5s.

Comment: In my experience, the purpose of HDF5 is storage (for out-of-memory calculations; transportability). For the calculations themselves, you should perform them *in memory if possible*, via `pandas`, `numpy`, etc. I don't know how large your data is, so I can't tell what will work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use nested dictionaries via `collections.defaultdict` for this:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

# read csv file
# df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None)

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'a', 'a1'],
                   ['A', 'a', 'a2'],
                   ['A', 'b', 'b1'],
                   ['A', 'b', 'b2'],
                   ['A', 'c', 'c1'],
                   ['A', 'c', 'c2']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

for row in df.itertuples():
    d[row[1]][row[2]].append(row[3])
```

**Result**

```
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {'A': defaultdict(list,
                         {'a': ['a1', 'a2'],
                          'b': ['b1', 'b2'],
                          'c': ['c1', 'c2']})})
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks, I will check out defaultdict. My solution is probably more hacky, but in case someone needs something customizable:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'a', 'a1'],
                   ['A', 'a', 'a2'],
                   ['A', 'b', 'b1'],
                   ['A', 'b', 'b2'],
                   ['A', 'c', 'c1'],
                   ['A', 'c', 'c2']],
                  columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])

cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
children = {p : {} for p in cols}
parent = {p : {} for p in cols}

for x in df.iterrows():
    for i in range(len(cols)-1):
        _parent = x[1][cols[i]]
        _child = x[1][cols[i+1]]

        parent[cols[i+1]].update({_child : _parent})
        if _parent in children[cols[i]]:
            children_list = children[cols[i]][_parent]
            children_list.add(_child)
            children[cols[i]].update({_parent : children_list})
        else:
            children[cols[i]].update({_parent : set([_child])})
```

Result:

```
    parent =
    {'col1': {},
     'col2': {'a': 'A', 'b': 'A', 'c': 'A'},
     'col3': {'a1': 'a', 'a2': 'a', 'b1': 'b', 'b2': 'b', 'c1': 'c', 'c2': 'c'}}
```

Then you can walk up and down your hierarchy.